# Dynamics CRM 2011 Upgrade, cases or Queues aren't shown - $v_0.get_query()["etc"].toString() error

Tags: dynamics-crm

After Dynamics CRM Upgrade, cases or Queues aren't shown. 
A $v_0.get_query()["etc"].toString() error is given.
Same question is asked ans answered in this link:
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/p/115109/321670#321670

the answer over there is :

1. Create a new CRM 2013 solution
2. Add Site Map
3. Export the solution
4. Open the solution zip file. Don't unzip the folder
5. Copy customizations.xml file from the ziped solution folder
6. Open the customizations.xml file with your favorite xml editor. Remember the golden rule "ALWAYS MAKE A BACK UP OF EVERYTHING YOU ARE ABOUT TO CHANGE"
7. locate   in the customizations.xml file
8. Delete Url="/CS/home_cases.aspx from the above
9. Save customizations.xml file
10. Delete the original customisations.xml file from the zipped solution folder
11. Copy the recently edited customizations.xml file to the zipped solution
12. Import the solution

**Is there an easier way?**

Answer (score 0):

1. download xrmtoolbox http://www.xrmtoolbox.com/.
2. open sitemap editor and connect to your organization.
3. load sitemap:

[image]

4.Press display XML:

[image]

5.Copy Xml content to notepad/notepad++ and find all "/CS/home_cases.aspx", it will help for next step.

6.Open site map treeview to the places found in step 5, remove from sitemap all url of "/CS/home_cases.aspx" by erasing it:
[image]

note there can be a few places, as found in step 5.

7. Update CRM

[image]